# Erlang distributed reverse string

Tags: erlang

I'm new to erlang, I can't figure out how to solve this exercise.
I need to reverse a long string by partitioning it in N substrings, reverse the single substrings and then join them to obtain the reverse of the original string.
Each substring need to be reversed by a different process.

My problems are:
1) How to split the string in N substrings of equal size?
2) How to join the string received by the other processes?

Can someone give me an example code? This is what I've done but it lacks the main parts:

```
% This function should split the string, spawn the processes
% and recombine the results
reverse(Str, N) -> % ...

sub_reverse() ->
    receive
        { From, SubStr } -> From ! { self(), lists:reverse(SubStr) }
    end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
-module(stackoverflow).
-export([reverse/2, join/0, sub_reverse/2]).

reverse(Str, N) ->
    % A process joining the reversed substrings.
    JoinPID = spawn(stackoverflow, join, []),

    % The step size is the length of Str divided by N.
    % TODO Handle remainder.
    Step = string:length(Str) div N,

    % The split points are calculated from end to start of Str.
    SplitPoints = lists:seq(string:length(Str) - Step, 0, -Step),

    % For each split point, spwan a process that reverts the substring for the
    % split point.
    lists:foreach(fun(From) ->
                    Substr = string:slice(Str, From, Step),
                    spawn(stackoverflow, sub_reverse, [JoinPID, Substr])
                  end,
                  SplitPoints).

join() ->
    receive
        {reverse_str, ReverseStr} ->
            io:format("~s", [ReverseStr]),
            join()
    end.

sub_reverse(JoinPID, SubStr) ->
    JoinPID ! {reverse_str, lists:reverse(SubStr)}.
```

**Edit**

This approach works but depends on the order of the spawend processes. If they return out of order, `join()` receives the parts out of order. So a possible improvement could be to tag each part with `From` so `join()` can join them in the correct order. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking in term of a pure recursive approach, but using stdlib functions is much easier. I've posted my version for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version after the answer:

```
-module(reverse).
-export([reverse/1, join/3, sub_reverse/3]).

reverse("") -> "";
reverse(Str) ->
    Step = ceil(string:length(Str) / 10),
    SplitPoints = lists:seq(0, string:length(Str) - 1, Step),

    JoinPid = spawn(reverse, join, [self(), [], length(SplitPoints)]),

    lists:foreach(
        fun (Start) ->
            IndexPos = Start div Step,
            SubStr = string:slice(Str, Start, Step),
            spawn(reverse, sub_reverse, [JoinPid, IndexPos, SubStr])
        end,
    SplitPoints),

    receive
        { joined, ReversedStr } -> io:format("~p", [ReversedStr])
    end.

join(ReversePid, Acc, N) ->
    case length(Acc) of
        N ->
            Parts = lists:sort(fun ({A, _}, {B, _}) -> A > B end, Acc),
            Str = string:join(lists:map(fun ({_, SubStr}) -> SubStr end, Parts), ""),
            ReversePid ! { joined, Str };
        _ ->
            receive
                {reversed, X} -> join(ReversePid, [X | Acc], N)
            end
    end.


sub_reverse(JoinPid, IndexPos, SubStr) ->
    JoinPid ! {reversed, { IndexPos, string:reverse(SubStr) } }.
```